# Regex Replace Special Characters gives different results in JS and Python

Tags: javascript, python, regex, unicode, special-characters

I am trying to replace all special characters using Regex and comparing between JavaScript (node.js v10.16.3) and Python (3.7.x)

```
\t kickref, first really multi-level referral program on the сrypto market, has reached over 20 000 users just in 2 days after its start on september 28.
```

Splitting the sentence into characters just to see the ASCII codes gives me this character array

```
'["\\t"," ","k","i","c","k","r","e","f",","," ","f","i","r","s","t"," ","r","e","a","l","l","y"," ","m","u","l","t","i","-","l","e","v","e","l"," ","r","e","f","e","r","r","a","l"," ","p","r","o","g","r","a","m"," ","o","n"," ","t","h","e"," ","с","r","y","p","t","o"," ","m","a","r","k","e","t",","," ","h","a","s"," ","r","e","a","c","h","e","d"," ","o","v","e","r"," ","2","0"," ","0","0","0"," ","u","s","e","r","s"," ","j","u","s","t"," ","i","n"," ","2"," ","d","a","y","s"," ","a","f","t","e","r"," ","i","t","s"," ","s","t","a","r","t"," ","o","n"," ","s","e","p","t","e","m","b","e","r"," ","2","8","."]'
```

This would be the ASCII codes for each letter

```
'[9,32,107,105,99,107,114,101,102,44,32,102,105,114,115,116,32,114,101,97,108,108,121,32,109,117,108,116,105,45,108,101,118,101,108,32,114,101,102,101,114,114,97,108,32,112,114,111,103,114,97,109,32,111,110,32,116,104,101,32,1089,114,121,112,116,111,32,109,97,114,107,101,116,44,32,104,97,115,32,114,101,97,99,104,101,100,32,111,118,101,114,32,50,48,32,48,48,48,32,117,115,101,114,115,32,106,117,115,116,32,105,110,32,50,32,100,97,121,115,32,97,102,116,101,114,32,105,116,115,32,115,116,97,114,116,32,111,110,32,115,101,112,116,101,109,98,101,114,32,50,56,46]'
```

The particularly important problem is due to the letter 'c' in the word crypto. Notice its ASCII code is 1089 in the Array

In JS my code to replace the regex looks as follows

```
const regexSpecialCharacters = new RegExp(/\W/, 'g');
text.replace(regexSpecialCharacters, ' ');
```

This yields the following sentence

```
kickref  first really multi level referral program on the  rypto market  has reached over 20 000 users just in 2 days after its start on september 28
```

The letter c got removed
In Python, my regex to do the exact same thing looks like this

```
import re
regex_special_characters = re.compile(r'\W')
regex_special_characters.sub(' ', text)
```

This gives me the following output

```
kickref  first really multi level referral program on the сrypto market  has reached over 20 000 users just in 2 days after its start on september 28
```

The letter c here has NOT been removed in Python
Can anyone kindly tell me why, I dont want JS removing the letter c either, what do I do?

Comment: `The particularly important problem is due to the letter 'c' in the word crypto`. That's because it's not a latin `c` it's a Cyrillic `с`.

Comment: `с` is a Cyrillic letter. `\W` in Python 3 is Unicode aware by default.

Comment: Just FYI, I pasted the word [here](https://r12a.github.io/uniview/?charlist=%D1%81rypto) to see the char names (no site affiliation on my part).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`с` is a Cyrillic letter. `\W` in Python 3 is Unicode aware by default, but it is not in JavaScript.

To also remove it in Python, pass [`re.ASCII` as the flag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.A):

```
import re
regex_special_characters = re.compile(r'\W', re.ASCII)
regex_special_characters.sub(' ', text)
```

More details from the `re.ASCII` documentation:

> Make `\w`, `\W`, `\b`, `\B`, `\d`, `\D`, `\s` and `\S` perform ASCII-only matching instead of full Unicode matching. This is only meaningful for Unicode patterns, and is ignored for byte patterns. Corresponds to the inline flag `(?a)`.

Comment: thanks! how do you make the character not get dropped in JS if you have any idea, if you use the flag u in JS it still drops the letter c

Comment: if you take this string s = 'hernández' and run the same regex in js and python to replace \W the python version due to unicode support doesnt drop a but the JS version does

Comment: @PirateApp You mean to make `\W` Unicode aware in JS RegExp? In Chrome, `replace(/[^\d\p{L}]/gu, ' ')` will work, but it will not work in FF and IE. For older browsers/JS environments, use approaches listed in [Javascript + Unicode regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode-regexes)